# divide mocha tests into files with common includes

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

so i have a test file with multiple `describe`s.

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import app from '../server/server'
import request from 'supertest'

const req = request(app);

describe('GET: /api/user', function () {
    it('should return valid user', function (done) {
        req
            .get('/api/user/' + userId)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                ...
                ...
                done();
            });
    });
});

...

describe('...', function () { ... });
```

i want to have separate file for each test, but i don't want to keep writing the `import`s for each file... any idea? (i have more `include`s, the code above is just a sample)

maybe there is a way to have an index file that runs first and then includes other files recursively?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have separate file for each test cases. But atlast include it in a common file like, **test.js**. and run the mocha test case on it.

For example,

```
test/lib/file1.js
test/lib/file2.js
test/lib/file3.js
test/lib/file4.js
test/lib/file5.js
```

Have a common file in the root of test folder, 
and include all the files.

```
require('./lib/file1.js');
require('./lib/file2.js');
require('./lib/file3.js');
require('./lib/file4.js');
require('./lib/file5.js');
```

and run as

```
mocha test/test.js
```

It will run all the test case for you.

Comment: i get an error **ReferenceError: req is not defined** when i move the first describe to a separate file as you suggested and include it in **test.js**

Comment: you have to import import request from 'supertest'

const req = request(app); in all the js file

Comment: yeah i suspected that... wanted to skip that. then i need to import **app** as well, and other dependencies that make use of **app** (like passport-stub for example)

Comment: yup, you need to import all files for that test case, if you are creating login test, you have to import all the files related to login. it will keep your test cases cleaner

Comment: what do you think about something like: **module.exports = function (req) {describe...};** for each test, and **require('./lib/getUser')(req);** in **test.js**?